# Search multidimensional array for value, if value doesn't exists, remove array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array containing child arrays in the following format:

```
[0] Array =>
    (
        [first] => Foo
        [second] => Bar
    )
[1] Array =>
    (
        [first] => Foo
        [second] => Bar
    )
[2] Array =>
    (
        [first] => Foo
        [second] => bingo
    )
[3] Array =>
    (
        [first] => jackpot
        [second] => bar
    )
```

I would like to search the entire array for 'bingo' and 'jackpot' and remove any child arrays that do not contain these values (in the above example, array 0 and array 1 should be removed).

I understand how to search the array using array_search('bingo', $myarray) but not how to remove the other two. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: 1. In your title you have *if doesn't exists*, so I'm a bit confused 2. *and remove the first two element (0, 1)* You mean the first 2 arrays or what?

Comment: Sorry, I've amended title.... in the example, I would like to remove array 0 and array 1 as these two do not contain either 'bingo' or 'jackpot'.

Comment: Ah so your *pattern* is either "jackpot" or "bingo" has to be in the array otherwise you want to remove it? (BTW: Add your attempt in your question! No matter if it worked or so just add what you tried, like with array_search or so)

Comment: Yes, exactly, so as array 0 and array 1 do not contain this pattern, they should be removed from the parent array... sorry, I am very new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just filter all arrays out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which does have an element with either `jackpot` or `bingo` in it, so only the arrays which doesn't have either `jackpot` or `bingo` in it will remain. After this I get all keys of these arrays with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and loop through them and unset they arrays)

```
<?php

    $keys = array_keys(array_filter($arr, function($v, $k){
        if(in_array("jackpot", $v) || in_array("bingo", $v) )
            return FALSE;
        return TRUE;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));

    foreach($keys as $key)
        unset($arr[$key]);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [first] => Foo
            [second] => bingo
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [first] => jackpot
            [second] => bar
        )

)
```

**EDIT:**

Even a simpler solution would be just to do this:

```
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if(!in_array("jackpot", $v) && !in_array("bingo", $v))
        unset($arr[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, but I seem to be getting an error from ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH : "Notice: Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - assumed 'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH'"

Comment: @user2726041 `echo phpversion();` = ... ? <5.6?

Comment: Ah! I am using 5.4.10

Comment: @user2726041 updated it again! Just refresh the page again and under edit this should do everything! Just print the array after it and you get your expected results